# How to interpret pattern in this scatter plot?

Tags: data-visualization, scatterplot, exploratory-data-analysis

How could you interpret the clear pattern that appears in each plot, in which it seems the points are very well aligned?

The dataset is `Olives`, from `extracat` package.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Look at univariate displays of each variable to see spikes. e.g. it seems that linolenic is often 0, 10, 20, ...

Comment: Please don't assume that everyone uses the software or data you use so that they recognise a dataset package reference! Software-independent references as URLs to datasets in a format that is widely readable are best.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you, Do you think this kind of repeating pattern can be due to incorrect measurements?

Comment: I am not an expert on olive oils, but it's hard to imagine a reason for (e.g.) values often being 10 and never 9 or 11 (as it appears from the graph). In some fields there are semi-quantitative conventions on small quantities so that what you seen has been filled in with numbers not in the original.

Comment: @NickCox not an expert either xD. Thank you very much, just wanted to know how one can interpret this kind of cases. Bests!

Comment: Rule of thumb from experience: Spikiness or granularity you can't explain is a hint of limited data quality, so watch out. (Examples of granularity you can explain: Lengths are multiples of 12.7 mm. They were originally to the nearest half inch. Times are multiples of 900000 ms. They were originally multiples of 15 min, e.g. appointments of patients.)